# How to determine iPhone/iPad target and iOS version while submission to AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, app-store, appstore-approval

I am uploading my App into AppStore. My app is displayed fine on iPhone, not on iPad. In addition, my App just works on iOS 6 or higher.

How can I determine these limitations to AppsStore review team while uploading my app? Are my limitations acceptable for the review team or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Xcode project - select the target (the one being deployed) and set its Deployment Target.

You have the ability to use older versions of iOS - just make sure you only use API included in the lowest version selected.  For example, don't use any of the new iOS7 backgrounding API if you are deploying for iOS6.  And if you do need to use API included only in newer versions of iOS, make sure to wrap that code in respondsToSelector logic to avoid crashes.

So yes, deploying to iOS6 is totally acceptable to the review team as long as its being compiled with the newest SDK.  This also allows users to download your app who haven't made the upgrade to iOS7 yet.

[image]

Comment: So, I've entered my deployment target as 6.0. Is it acceptable for the AppStore Review team or not?

Comment: Updated answer - it is acceptable.  Just make sure you are on Xcode 5.0 (with the new SDK)

Comment: And how about my iPhone target? Is it OK for Appstore for an App to just run on iPhone (Not iPad)?

Comment: if you will choose Devices universial in this image, your app can run on ipad and iphone . But you have to set your images to ipad

Comment: If you only deploy for iPhone, it will run on the iPad anyhow. But in the not so pretty "zoom 1x / 2x" mode. Thousands of apps work this way. See here: https://support.apple.com/kb/ht4082